# Is 3 amperes at 5V drawing the same power as 3 amperes at 12V?

Tags: 12v, solar-energy

I know that amperes are volts x watts. If I draw 5V at 3 amperes, is it almost the same as drawing 12V at 3 amperes from a 12V system? I expect the 5V would draw more as there is inefficiency when dropping the voltage.

What I'm looking to do is hook a Google Wifi up to an SLA battery and solar panel and I'm attempting to calculate the run time for the draw at 5V 3amperes.

Comment: Your math is a bit strange. 3 A at 5 V are 15 W, 3 A at 12 V are 36 W, more than twice times the power.

Comment: Your power formula is wrong - it should be watts = volts times amps (P = EI).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to hook a Google Wifi up to an SLA battery, you need a DC to DC converter to adapt the voltage. The Wifi needs 5 V but the battery delivers 12 V.

If you use a linear voltage regulator to produce the 5V, the current at 12 V and 5 V is the same, input power to the regulator is 3 A at 12 V = 36 W and output power is 3 A at 5 V = 15 W. The difference between input and output power is wasted, so 36 W - 15 W = 21 W are lost.

If you use a switching DC to DC converter, the input current of this converter is lower than the output current. An ideal converter with 100 % efficiency would take 15 W from the battery to produce the 15 W for the wifi. So the current at 12 V is only 15 W / 12 V = 1.25 A.

If the battery has 60 Ah, (ampere hours), the run time with the linear regulator is 60 Ah / 3 A = 20 h. If the switching DC to DC converter is used the run time is much longer, 60 Ah / 1.25 A = 48 h.

Real converters need a little power for themselve so we should assume the run time to be about 10 % less, so 18 hours or 43.2 hours.

Answer (score 6):

> I know that amperes are volts x watts

That’s incorrect.

$$
\begin{aligned}
P &= I \times V \ \ \ \ /V \\
\frac{P}{V} &= I,
\end{aligned}
$$

where *P* is power, *I* is current, *V* is voltage.

Amperes x Volts = Watts

3A x 5V = 15W

3A x 12V = 36W

Answer (score 3):

For DC circuits (e.g. a battery supplying power to a circuit) power (watts) is amps times volts. So 5V at 3A is 15 watts; 12V at 3A is 36 watts.